# How to filter data with a subquery in Cognos Dashboard?

Tags: analytics, data-analysis, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I need to implement "IN clause" and filter out data from some other query. How can I implement this in Cognos Dashboard.

Comment: Can you give an example? Does this have to be a dashboard, maybe you can do this in a report where you have a little more control?

Comment: In report I found out that we can use reference query , but I need the solution in dashboard only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.